# Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4 (ISO) is backward compatible?

Tags: windows, windows-7, compatibility, winapi

On windows 7 if i install Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4 (ISO)  is that enough to work with vs 2008 or should i install also 3.5 sdk ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote from the [Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4 release notes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowssdk/archive/2010/05/25/released-windows-sdk-for-windows-7-and-net-framework-4.aspx):

> - .NET Framework:  Create applications    that target the .NET
>     Framework    versions 2.0 (SP2) , 3.0
>     (SP2) , 3.5    (SP1), 4.
> - Visual Studio:  Use the resources in    this SDK with Visual Studio
>     versions    2005, 2008, and 2010,
>     including    Express editions (not all
>     features    work with all versions of
>     Visual    Studio).

Thus yes, includes backwards compatibility into the lines described in the release notes.

Answer (score 0):

When you install VS it will install the .NET framework it needs